# Sleep windows service until Thread timer starts

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I'm creating a windows service to run some task withing intervals. Here, user can set the task start time (first run) and the task intervals. In my program in `OnStart` event, set the timer and wait for trigger.

But the problem is main thread dies before thread timer starts. So I tried to add  `Thread.CurrentThread.Join()` and `Sleep()` until timer start. But after I install the windows service I cannot start the windows service, because `sleep` or `block` is in `OnStart` event. So it stuck, or sleep so long time and shows some exception.

Simply what I need is stop exit main thread untill Thread timer trigger.

```
  public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
  {
    TimerCallback timer_delegate;
    Timer houskeep_timer;

   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      SettingReader settings = new SettingReader();
      if (settings.init())
      {
        timer_delegate = new TimerCallback(houseKeep);
        houskeep_timer = new Timer(timer_delegate, "testing", 33333100000, 44450000);
        //Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
      }
    }

     private void houseKeep(object setting_obj)
    {
        string message = (string)setting_obj;
        writeToLogFile(message);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Service main thread is an event loop.  Why should it exit 'early'?

Comment: Rather than write a service that spends most of its time doing nothing but occupying memory, you should write a simple console application and schedule it using Windows Task Scheduler. [Programs are not cats](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/).

Comment: On another note, you want your timer to wait 385 days before the first time it fires, and then fire evern 12 hours or so? You might consider using `TimeSpan.FromHours` or `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` for your arguments rather than milliseconds.

Comment: @Jim: thank you for the information. your second answer looks more useful to me. could you explain a bit how can i user TimeSpan.FromHours with Thread Timers

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use timers for this, I'd use a normal exe and set it up in the task scheduler.  Otherwise you're just implementing your own scheduling, with much less functionality to what is already built in to windows.

See [Jon Galloway post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx) on why not to use a service to run scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

note that this is not the best way to do multithreading stuff, but it may be a solution to your problem.
use a boolean variable that is global to the treads. set it on main tread and look if it changes! change it in the service tread when you wish the main thread to exit. after that the main thread will exit at the time you want. no need to do any `invoke` method or something as long as the flags you are creating in-between the treads are `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you need

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private System.Threading.AutoResetEvent are = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            new System.Threading.Thread(mt) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
        }

        private void mt()
        {
            // Set up timer here

            // wait for OnStop indefinitely
            are.WaitOne();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            are.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

The OnStart will start a thread that waits indefinitely for the OnStop. It is in this thread that you will create your timers.